# Bootstrap 3 Column Wraps in Portrait View Only

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a very simple layout going in the footer of a website using Bootstrap 3:

```
<div id="reviews" class="row">
    <div class="container">
        <h3><i class="icon-comment"></i>Review<i class="icon-comment"></i></h3>
        <div class="review col-xs-12">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="review-meta row">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="review-author col-xs-11">Author Name</div>
                <div class="add-review col-xs-1 text-center"><i class="icon-plus"></i></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For some reason, in .review-meta, the col-xs-1 wraps to the next line when viewed on an iPhone - and only in portrait view. (Which is to say .review-author and .add-review should be side-by-side). I haven't been able to figure out why. Would anyone be able to lend a hand?

Notes:
- I'm having no issues in any other browsers or in landscape mode.
- I've tried it on the iPad with no issues
- There are no additional styles applied to the elements

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: your markup is a little off, can you clarify what the expected result should be?

Comment: Try add `col-sm-11` instead. It may be that the width of the screen is not compatible with the class used.

Comment: @koala_dev I expect .review-author and .add-review to be side-by-side.

Comment: @PiLHA Unfortunately that doesn't work. It just causes the elements to stack (as expected).

Comment: There's an open Bootstrap bug about this: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/13221

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @PiLHA suggested, it seems bootstrap's 3 grid system does not support 1 column spans in screens with a width less than approximately 360px. The issue comes from the fixed padding of `15px` that is added on each side to each column.

Now some math to explain the issue:

A one column span `.col-xs-1` has a defined width of: `8.333333333333332%;` (that's 100/12)

In a screen of 320px like the iPhone's that's roughly equal to `27px;` but the combined padding is forcing its width to `30px`. Those extra pixels are the ones causing the `<div>` to break to the next line.

So an easy fix would be to just decrease the padding in that column size:

```
.col-xs-1 {
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

Or you could also decide to use `col-xs-10` and `col-xs-2` in your markup

That being said, you should take a note on what @SeanRyan posted in his answer and fix your markup, I was going to post something similar but I believe his answer is well laid out and there's no need to repeat the same pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Could be a bug. That being said, there are some general issues with how your code is laid out. Based on my current understanding of the Bootstrap 3 grid, here is a cleaner way:

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="reviews" class="row">
    <h3 class="col-xs-12"><i class="icon-comment"></i>Review<i class="icon-comment"></i></h3>
    <div class="review col-xs-12">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </p>
      <div class="review-meta row">
        <div class="review-author col-xs-11">Author Name</div>
        <div class="add-review col-xs-1 text-center"><i class="icon-plus"></i></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

1. Removed duplicate .container elements.
2. Added grid class to h3 to bring it inline with other elements.
3. Nested row should fall within .col div (at least according to the docs).

I starting thinking that #3 was unintentional, in that you didn't want your 11/1 row to be nested. If that is the case, the code should look more like:

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="reviews" class="row">
    <h3 class="col-xs-12"><i class="icon-comment"></i>Review<i class="icon-comment"></i></h3>
    <div class="review col-xs-12">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="review-meta row">
    <div class="review-author col-xs-11">Author Name</div>
    <div class="add-review col-xs-1 text-center">icon</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am not able to test on an iPhone right now, so I am hoping this will clear the issue for you.

Comment: Thanks @Sean Ryan for the information, very useful. A few follow-ups: 1. I've avoided wrapping everything in a .container since the design requires full width backgrounds. The only way I've found to reliable do that is to use .container classes within rows. 2. I've added the grid class to the h3. 3. I didn't realize that nested rows needed to fall within a .col div. I'll do that now. Thanks!