# Bootstrap - col-xs is collapsing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Reading the bootstrap3 documentation, it says that the col-xs-* columns always display horizontally and never collapse/stack.

But I'm having a problem where it's actually collapsing.

I'm working with nested cols

First I divided my viewport in 2 columns.

Then I put an col-xs grid nested inside one of the columns. I was expecting this xs grid to never collapse but it is collapsing.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <div class="row" style="background-color: olive">
                <div class="col-xs-1">
                    <div style="border:1px solid black">8</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <div style="border:1px solid black">
                        text
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-5">
                    <div style="border:1px solid black">
                        more text
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
            <div style="background-color: #ccc:">hello world</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wWyLH/

Comment: Check out [This Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365908/bootstrap-3-column-wraps-in-portrait-view-only), I believe the accepted answer will fix your problem.

Comment: Makes sense, so the problem is the col-xs-1 which can never result in a box less than 30px because of the default paddings.