# using nested columns in bootstrap gives unexpected result

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid

I am trying to use nested columns. This is my HTML:

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="color: #FFFFFF">
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            1</div>
        <div class="col-xs-10">
            <div class="row" style="color: #FFFFFF">
                <div class="col-xs-4" style="background-color: #0099FF">
                    2</div>
                <div class="col-xs-4" style="background-color: #33CC33">
                    3</div>
                <div class="col-xs-4" style="background-color: #CC33FF">
                    4</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            5</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the output:

[image]

Why does the '5' appear on the next line?

Comment: Hi folks. Thanks for your responses. For some reason I pasted the wrong markup. I have updated it just now. As you can see I am obeying the '12' column ruke here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the `col-xs-10` outside the `.row` for the negative margins on the nested cols to work correctly..

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row" style="color: #FFFFFF">
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                1</div>
            <div class="col-xs-10">
                <div class="row" style="color: #FFFFFF">

                        <div class="col-xs-4" style="background-color: #0099FF">
                            2</div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4" style="background-color: #33CC33">
                            3</div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4" style="background-color: #CC33FF">
                            4</div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                5</div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/nyv0SEi3B4

Comment: Hi, I tried this and when I resized the window to the screen size i posted it still gave the result i illustrated in my question?

Comment: There is always going to be wrapping/stacking at widths less than 360 px.. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365908/bootstrap-3-column-wraps-in-portrait-view-only

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a row in bootstrap can have only 12 coloumns, but your coloumn 5 has exceeded it

Try reducing the coloumns size for 2,3, and 4 to col-xs-3 and try.