# Bootstrap: why does the col-1 flow down (stack up) when it's not supposed to?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

This is my HTML / CSS code :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-1">
            <img src="http://www.unixstickers.com/image/cache/data/stickers/jsfiddle/JSfiddle-blue-w-type.sh-600x600.png" style="width:20px;" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-11">
            <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
            <span>Ut luctus consectetur dapibus.</span>
            <span>Phasellus vestibulum dui non lacus ultricies egestas.</span>
            <span>Aenean eros lorem, tincidunt eget eros nec, suscipit egestas elit</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please see my jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/na6pd9he/5/

this is the correct behavior :

[image]

When I'm in a very small size, the div goes down :

[image]

Why, and how can I avoid this ?

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365908/bootstrap-3-column-wraps-in-portrait-view-only and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39806334/bootstrap-xs-columns-wrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because there's normally 15px of padding in a column (on both sides) but you can easily reduce that padding by applying a Bootstrap 4 class like `p-1` or `p-2`.

The `p-0` class would remove the padding completely but I assume that you do want to keep some padding and the `p-2` class prevents stacking even on the smallest screens (320px) while still providing the benefit of padding.

Working code snippet:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-1 p-2">
            <img src="http://www.unixstickers.com/image/cache/data/stickers/jsfiddle/JSfiddle-blue-w-type.sh-600x600.png" style="width:20px;" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-11">
            <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
            <span>Ut luctus consectetur dapibus.</span>
            <span>Phasellus vestibulum dui non lacus ultricies egestas.</span>
            <span>Aenean eros lorem, tincidunt eget eros nec, suscipit egestas elit</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Reference:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/

Comment: Thanks for explanations

Answer (score 0):

If you remove padding from the two elements they will not collapse.

```css
.col-1, .col-11{
  padding:0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-1">
            <img src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/app/uploads/2016/09/sweet-home-icon.jpg" style="width:20px;" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-11">
            <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
            <span>Ut luctus consectetur dapibus.</span>
            <span>Phasellus vestibulum dui non lacus ultricies egestas.</span>
            <span>Aenean eros lorem, tincidunt eget eros nec, suscipit egestas elit</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```